# Get multiple rows using select top 1 and joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, northwind

I'm working on northwind database.

I have to select the newest and the oldest order/orders (could be multiple with same date).

Is it possible without using subqueries and top 1, only by joining tables?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Answer (score 0):

Using a CTE:

```
WITH orders_rnk AS (
  SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY order_date ASC) AS rnk
  FROM orders
)
SELECT * from orders_rn WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Using a JOIN:

```
SELECT o.*
FROM orders AS o
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders AS o2
  ON o.order_date > o2.order_date
WHERE o2.order_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, second option is the one I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `TOP 1` but add `WITH TIES` keyword.

[link to MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Per MS documentation

> WITH TIES **Returns two or more rows** that tie for last place in the
> limited results set. You must use this argument with the ORDER BY
> clause. WITH TIES might cause more rows to be returned than the value
> specified in expression. For example, if expression is set to 5 but
> two additional rows match the values of the ORDER BY columns in row 5,
> the result set will contain seven rows.

Exmaple

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES 
FROM tableA A JOIN TableB
ON A.ID=B.ID
ORDER BY A.column1
```